# Clone & remove incrementing divs separately without deleting the first div

Tags: jquery

I'm using query to clone divs but when removing them I want the first one to in place and not be removed, can't get my head round it.

Here's the jquery

```
function updateClonedInput(index, element) {
$(element).appendTo("body").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  index);
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_" + index);
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_" + index + "']; ?>");
$(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_button_" + index);
}

$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(){
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
var new_Input = $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone();
updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(){
$(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

$(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
})
});
```

Here's a fiddle of my working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/13/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it (short on coffee today) you want to clone elements and then destroy the elements but you also  destroy / remove the original.

I too had this problem. The issue can be solved by creating a base set of elements you keep hidden and when you clone them be sure to change the selector (id or class) name of the cloned element.

When you destroy the cloned element, you won't destroy the hidden element and your base original.  Also in this way you create individual addressable clones which too can be modified or cloned against further.

Always having your base elements saved away on the browser. This is of course not the only way but only one suggestion. I often store larger "data" in the data of the window not visible at all the "browse source" but that is outside the scope of your question.

Remember after you clone, to  changed the cloned .show();

Comment: An example can be found [example](https://github.com/alexmac131/mediaData/blob/master/js/mediaPlayer.js) here.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, That's exactly what i'm trying to do, I've taken a look at the code you supplied but I think it's getting late and I can't figure it out, do you have a working fiddle?

Comment: I working fiddle, I will have to find out what fiddle is... other than one you play with a bow... It was a learning exercise for myself and I am thinking of writing my own bit of code to handle the the entries with my own search engine / Regex as my next on writing widget learning exercise.  Good luck though.